# scrolling to the beginning of an anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having trouble with scrolling to anchors.
I am having 3 problems:

1. When I am over two panels and I click a link to one of the panels. Nothing happens.
   [image: Neither A or B will work]
2. When I am on for example D and I click C it goes to the end of C.

   #### Before clicking on C:

   [image]

   #### After clicking on C:

   [image: Goes to the end of C]
3. When I add any jquery or javascript like this to scroll to the hashes

   `function scrollTo(hash) {
       location.hash = "#" + hash;
    }`

   it does not seem to work.

---

### What I would like:

I would like the link to go to the beginning of the div (the furthest left of the div) no matter where the user is.

---

## My code

I have a page like this:

### HTML:

```
<ul class="links">
    <li><a href="#a">A</a></li>
    <li><a href="#b">B</a></li>
    <li><a href="#c">C</a></li>
    <li><a href="#d">D</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="panels">
    <div class="panel" id="a">I'am A</div>
    <div class="panel" id="b">I'am B</div>
    <div class="panel" id="c"><span class="stupid-long-content">I'am C (very long)</span></div>
    <div class="panel" id="d">I'am D</div>
</div>
```

Where each div is this size of the screen through **css** like this:

```
*
{
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body
{
   height:100%;  
}
body
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;  
}

.panels
{
    white-space: nowrap;
    height: inherit;
}

.panel
{
   height: inherit;
   font-size: 20px;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 60px;
   display: inline-block;
   min-width: 100%;
}

.stupid-long-content
{
    width: 3000px;
    display: block;
}
```

## [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/N9B3Y/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery scrollLeft function and prevent the default browser handling:

```
$('.links a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (this.hash)
        $('body, html').scrollLeft($(this.hash).offset().left);
});
```

Here is the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N9B3Y/2/).